Extracting Zip contents into a flat directory using Kotlin
I'm working on some code to parse and extract the contents of a zip file. I finally figured out how to deal with nested zip archives (see: Extracting a Zip archive containing nested zip files using Kotlin for more details). However, now I am running into a new issue. I want all the files to be extracted into a single directory regardless of where they were nested. The code I have currently is creating directories for nested files and placing the extracted files there. What can I do to get everything into a single directory without having to shift files around after the function has run?
My code currently looks like:
internal fun File.unzipServiceFile(toPath: String): List<File>
{
    val retFiles = mutableListOf<File>()
    val stream =ZipInputStream(this.inputStream())
    stream.unzipServiceFile( toPath, retFiles)

    return retFiles
}

private fun ZipInputStream.unzipServiceFile( toPath: String, files:MutableList<File>) {

    var entry = nextEntry
    println("Parsing entry $entry")
    while( entry != null){
        println("entry: " + entry.name)
        //if there are nested zip files, we need to extract them
        if (entry.name.endsWith(".zip")) {
            //we need to go deeper
            ZipInputStream(this).unzipServiceFile(  toPath, files)
        }
        else if (entry.name.endsWith(".json") && !entry.isDirectory && !entry.name.startsWith(".") && !entry.name.startsWith(
                "_"
            )
        ) {
            val file = File("$toPath/${entry.name}")
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, readBytes())
            files.add(file)
            println("Added file ${file.path}")
        }

        entry = nextEntry
    }
    println()
}

Additional info:
The folder before being zipped:

The output of the code:


By the way, Kotlin has some useful utility functions that make Apache FileUtils redundant. For example, instead of FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile you can use File.writeBytes. (Or you might prefer to use the newer Path.writeBytes.)

entry.name is not just the file name, it may also contain a directory component. If you strip that when creating the output file then everything will be extracted in the same directory.
One way to do it:
val file = File("$toPath/${File(entry.name).name}")

